# Converting html file to standalone desktop application

Tags: c#, html, desktop-application

Do i need a software or is there any other way to convert a html file into a standalone desktop application?

Comment: Not that i know of, however you could always create a standalone application with an embedded webbrowser and load the page

Comment: Yes, you need software. Without software, the HTML file would just open in a standard web browser. Software recommendations are off-topic for this website.

Comment: yup!! thanks.Would be helpful if some softwares are recommended ,but as it is off-topic i'll try googling.

Comment: Is it even possible that i can access a HTML application through URL without that application locally present in my system.!! Are you getting it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing the extension name from .html/.htm to.hta.

Comment: Is it even possible that i should access this HTML application through URL without that application locally present in my system.!! Are you getting it?

Comment: It would popup file download dialog through URL and the href attribute in HTML should be full URL.If you want a desktop application transformed from HTML which can also be accessed through URL,solutions like Node-WebKit would be  better choices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)?

> Build cross platform desktop apps with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS

Comment: yup!!..I don't know why my system doesn't support Electron!